# Make popup.html remember settings

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, popupmenu

Quite new to chrome extensions, so any advice is welcome. When I click the extension icon in chrome, the popup comes up, I check checkboxes & select options in dropdowns, but when I close it and reopen it, it's all resetted. How would I make the popup.html remember checkboxes that are checked and the selections in the dropdown?

Comment: You need use a jq cookie plugin to store clicked, checked info to cookies and reuse them later. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0):

The chrome.storage API allows you to store, retrieve, and track changes to user data.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage